# Why is $\mathbb{F}_q^{*}/(\mathbb{F}_q^{*})^n\rightarrow \boldsymbol{\mu}_n: \overline{x}\mapsto x^{(q-1)/n} $ a group isomorphism?

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote a finite field. Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer such that $n\mid q-1$. Hence the $n$-th roots of unity $\boldsymbol{\mu}_n$ are contained in $\mathbb{F}_q$. 
Why is the map
$$\mathbb{F}_q^{*}/(\mathbb{F}_q^{*})^n\rightarrow \boldsymbol{\mu}_n: \overline{x}\mapsto x^{(q-1)/n} $$
an isomorphism of groups?
It is clearly well defined. But why is it a (iso)morphism ?

Comment: What is its kernel?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is a cyclic group. Now, apply what you know about cyclic groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to see this. I think I learned this particular argument from Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic* (He needs the statement for $n = 2$ to prove quadratic reciprocity). First define $\mathbf F_q^* \to \mu_n$ by $x \mapsto x^{(q - 1)/n}$. Fix $x \in \mathbf F_q^*$, and let $y$ be an element in some extension of $\mathbf F_q$ such that $y^n = x$. For $x$ to be an $n$-th power in $\mathbf F_q$ we need $y \in \mathbf F_q$, i.e. $y^{q - 1} = x^{(q - 1)/n} = 1$. So the kernel of our map really is $\mathbf F_q^{*n}$. Now note that $\mathbf F_q^{*n}$ has order $(q - 1)/n$ because $\mathbf F_q^*$ is a cyclic group.

*Edit.* Is the question simply, "Why is this a homomorphism of groups?" The multiplicative group is commutative, and hence $(xy)^k = x^ky^k$ for all $k$, and in particular for $k = (q - 1)/n$.